# Is it possible to detect the variable of a using from another function and access that variable?

Tags: c#, scope, using

I have a function which calls another function. I want to know if within that second function I can detect if it is being invoked from the first function within a using-scope. If I can detect it, I want to access the variable inside that using-scope. I cannot send the variable through a parameter.

For example:

```
// Normal call to OtherFunction
void function1()
{
    SomeClass.OtherFunction();
}


// Calling using someVar
void function2()
{
    using(var someVar = new someVar())
    {
        SomeClass.OtherFunction();
    }
}

// Calling using other variable, in this case, similar behaviour to function1()
void function3()
{
    using(var anotherVar = new anotherVar())
    {
        SomeClass.OtherFunction();
    }
}

class SomeClass
{
    static void OtherFunction()
    {
         // how to know if i am being called inside a using(someVar)
         // and access local variables from someVar
    }
}
```

Comment: Why can't you send them as parameters?

Comment: Are `someVar` and `anotherVar` allowes to have the same base class?

Comment: @programmer93, because is in an assembly that is used in a lot of projects and i cannot rebuild all of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the same mechanisme as `System.Transaction.TransasctionScope`. This only works if all context's can have the same base class. The base class registerers himself in a static property during construction and removes himself at dispose. If another `Context` is already active, it is surpressed until the newest `Context` is disposed again.

```
using System;

namespace ContextDemo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DetectContext();
            using (new ContextA())
                DetectContext();
            using (new ContextB())
                DetectContext();
        }

        static void DetectContext()
        {
            Context context = Context.Current;
            if (context == null)
                Console.WriteLine("No context");
            else 
                Console.WriteLine("Context of type: " + context.GetType());
        }
    }

    public class Context: IDisposable
    {
        #region Static members

        [ThreadStatic]
        static private Context _Current;

        static public Context Current
        {
            get
            {
                return _Current;
            }
        }

        #endregion

        private readonly Context _Previous;

        public Context()
        {
            _Previous = _Current;
            _Current = this;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _Current = _Previous;
        }
    }

    public class ContextA: Context
    {
    }

    public class ContextB : Context
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, the whole point of a `using` is that it deterministically calls the cleanup code, which can include resetting the context.  Please note though that maybe you should use a stack and not only a single variable.

Comment: @Ben: Well... in essence I am using a stack. Every context is stacked on another and holds a reference to the previous context. The very first context has a reference to `null`. See it as a 'linked stack', where the constructor acts like a `Push` and the `Dispose` acts like a `Pop`.

Comment: Ahh, I missed that you implemented your own singly linked list.  Yes that takes care of nesting just like a stack would.

Answer (score 0):

Create public getter for a variable you can access from within the Someclass.OtherFunction() and set the variable value depending what function did the call, so you can identify the caller.